# Login Required is taking away my wagtail documents

Tags: python, html, django, wagtail

```
@login_required
def view_architect_page(request): args = {'user': request.user} return render(request, 'DEMOAPP/architect_page.html', args)
```

This is my view. It redirects me to my login page and then allows me into the page after logged in but it doesnt display the wagtail information. I know its not working becuase when i "view live" in wagtail, the files show up...

Below is my models.py

```
class ArchitectPage(Page):
search_fields = Page.search_fields + [

   ]  # these are if adding a search to the website

# content tab panels
content_panels = Page.content_panels + [ MultiFieldPanel( [InlinePanel('architect_pdf', max_num=20, min_num=0, label="architect pdf")], heading="architect pdf" ), ]
# what to call the panels on wagtail
edit_handler = TabbedInterface([ ObjectList(content_panels, heading='Content'), ObjectList(Page.promote_panels, heading='SEO'), ObjectList(Page.settings_panels, heading='Settings', classname='settings'),
classname settings adds the cog
])


class ArchitectDownloads(Orderable):
page = ParentalKey(ArchitectPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='architect_pdf')
architect_pdf = models.ForeignKey(
'wagtaildocs.Document', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+' )
   panels = [
    DocumentChooserPanel('architect_pdf'),
]
```

This is my html which doesnt show up becuase of this login required view...

```
<ul>
    {% for download in page.architect_pdf.all %} {# loop over the ArchitectDownload objects #}
        {% with doc=download.architect_pdf %} {# retrieve the Document object for each one #}
            <li><a href="{{ doc.url }}">{{ doc.title }}</a></li>
        {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Ive been commenting this url in and out and can see the view is the issue

```
path('architect-page/', views.view_architect_page),
```

Anyone have any ideas how I can later the view so its even in the models.py with the declaration of the wagtail class?

Comment: Any reason you're not using Wagtail's built-in privacy controls? https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/privacy.html

Comment: @gasman I couldnt get it to work for some reason. I was trying at it for a good number of hours and couldnt get it going